# Blackduck Policy Violation

Tags: typescript, node-postgres, pg-promise, blackduck

For a TypeScript project we use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library and it depends on [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).

For a daily scan we use Blackduck and it detects "High Vulnerability Security Issue" as follows:

```
2024-01-30 13:20:37 UTC INFO  [main] --- Policy rule "High Vulnerability Security Issue" was violated by component "node_postgres:1.1.1" (https://*************************/api/components/004e0535-3fc4-4b69-a943-dfbc61df9517/versions/763e60b6-4bde-4f1e-bcd8-73e84fd18a09).
2024-01-30 13:20:37 UTC INFO  [main] --- Policy rule "High Vulnerability Security Issue" has a fatal severity type: Blocker with description: High Vulnerability security issue, with a CVSS score greater than or equal to 7.0
```

So, at the end because of the security issue it fails the security scan.

Our pg-promise entry in the package.json is

```
{
    "name": "rds-trigger-handler",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "mysql": "^2.18.1",
      "pg-promise": "^11.0.0"
    }
  }
```

Even though we tried different pg-promise version(^11.5.4, ^11.5.0, ^11.4.3) the error we get did not change. It always says `was violated by component "node_postgres:1.1.1"`. However, the node-postgres has no versioning.

`npm why pg`:

```
pg@8.11.3
node_modules/pg
  peer pg@">=8.0" from pg-pool@3.6.1
  node_modules/pg-pool
    pg-pool@"^3.6.1" from pg@8.11.3
  pg@"8.11.3" from pg-promise@11.5.4
  node_modules/pg-promise
    pg-promise@"^11.0.0" from the root project
```

How can we solve the issue, has anyone had same issue before?

Comment: I have edited question with the result, thanks.

Comment: You should investigate it against `node-postgres` and `Blackduck`, while `pg-promise` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Also, opened a [case](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) for [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/3138) itself. After reaching out to the management console of the Blackduck, it gave us the ID of the vulnerability which is [CVE-2017-16082](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-16082).  So, we are thinking about why did we get this error now. For this question, there is nothing to do, thanks!